# Searchkick word_start match with nested field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

I have a Rails app with searchkick gem. My model has a nested JSON field. I try to make it searchable with word_start match. When I set in explicitly like:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord 
  searchkick word_start: [:nested_data_field]
end
```

I does not work, and I get error:

```
{"type"=>"mapper_parsing_exception", "reason"=>"failed to parse [nested_data_field]", "caused_by"=>{"type"=>"illegal_state_exception", "reason"=>"Can't get text on a START_OBJECT at 1:401"}} on item with id '2596'
```

How can I make this nested JSON field to match word_start?

I found the same issue here https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/issues/1149 - but it has no result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in this case, you have to explicitly define how fields should index in elasticsearch

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord 
  searchkick word_start: [:author_name, author_country]

  def search_data # override indexing fields
    {
     tite: self.title,
     date: self.created_at,
     author_name: author[:name], # nested json(author field)
     author_country: author[:country],
     comments_ids: comments.map(&:id) # index as an array of ids       
    }
  end
end
```