# Searchkick Nested Data

Tags: elasticsearch, searchkick, elasticsearch-nested

The manual states this (https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#nested-data):

> **Nested Data**
>
> To query nested data, use dot notation.

```
User.search "san", fields: ["address.city"], where: {"address.zip_code" => 12345}
```

This simply doesn't work or the example given needs more qualification.

In my case I have `ExpenditureItem` which belongs_to: `Expenditure` so I try this:

```
ExpenditureItem.search("*", where: { "expenditure.budget_id": '2'})
```

which results in nothing.  I know in my `search_data` I can set:

```
budget_id: expenditure.budget_id
```

but from the example it seems the entire point is to be able to complete quick and easy nested searches.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Nested queries can only be performed on nested fields, specified as such in your mapping. You're gonna have to [override](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55438746/8160318) your default indexing which is the equivalent of explicitly defining it in your [ElasticSearch mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/nested.html#nested-fields-array-objects).

Comment: So what you are saying is in the example not shown in the `search_data`
is `address_city: address[:city]` etc.?

Comment: What I'm saying is `expenditure.budget_id: expenditure[:budget_id]`.

Answer (score 0):

Associations are not automatically indexed as nested data.

In your case, you would need to specifically include the associations that you want to index in your `search_data` method.

For example, to include all fields in your `ExpenditureItem` model as well as the `Expenditure` association, you could do:

```rb
def search_data
  as_json.merge({
    expenditure: expenditure.as_json
  })
end
```

If you don't need to index all attributes, ou can then of course modify the `as_json` method params to include or exclude the attributes and instance methods that you require in your index.

Also, to make indexing more performant, be sure to [include the association](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#indexing) in the `search_import` scope, e.g.

```rb
scope :search_import, -> { includes(:expenditure) }
```