# How can I search record stored in jsonb field using search kick on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

I have jsonb field **ocr_extract** in **products**, and I have a search input that should query the products through **ocr_extract[:text]** field.

Data stored on **ocr_extract** field in this format:

```
ocr_extract:
   "[{\"text\": \"raa\", \"x\": 550, \"y\": 195, \"w\": 19, \"h\": 3}, \n                       {\"text\": \"ee\", \"x\": 570, \"y\": 194, \"w\": 134, \"h\": 8}, \n                       {\"text\": \"sinter\", \"x\": 752, \"y\": 193, \"w\": 76, \"h\": 9}, \n                       {\"text\": \"aoe\", \"x\": 806, \"y\": 180, \"w\": 17, \"h\": 6}, \n                       {\"text\": \"3se\", \"x\": 853, \"y\": 195, \"w\": 137, \"h\": 3}, \n                       {\"text\": \"mr\", \"x\": 991, \"y\": 195, \"w\": 52, \"h\": 3}, \n                       {\"text\": \"sea\", \"x\": 636, \"y\": 216, \"w\": 17, \"h\": 6}, \n                       {\"text\": \"2\", \"x\": 763, \"y\": 208, \"w\": 13, \"h\": 6}, \n                       {\"text\": \"=\", \"x\": 804, \"y\": 216, \"w\": 10, \"h\": 6}, \n                       {\"text\": \"16\", \"x\": 962, \"y\": 216, \"w\": 17, \"h\": 6}]"
```

This is how my code looks like:

product.rb

```
searchkick index_name: "products"

  def search_data
    {
      id: self.id,
      ocr_extract: self.ocr_extract,
      created_at: self.created_at
    }
  end
```

products_controller.rb

```
Product.search(query, fields: [:ocr_extract], match: :word_middle)
```

Answer (score 0):

Question is quite old but came first on my search results so this might help others.

I have a scenario where I want to use the [Mobility Gem](https://github.com/shioyama/mobility) to store translations in database as a jsonb column, and make it searchable no matter the user locale.
The column is therefore looking like `name: {"en"=>"dog", "fr"=>"chien"}` regarding the animal model.

If you aim to simply search on the `Animal` name matching all possible translations currently stored, you could follow this answer [Searchkick word_start match with nested field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55430115/searchkick-word-start-match-with-nested-field)

Now your Animal class would look like

```rb
class Animal < ApplicationRecord
  extend Mobility
  translates :name, fallbacks: { fr: :en }

  searchkick

  def search_data
    {
      # Indexes as an array of values with the stored translations
      name: JSON.parse(name_for_database).values 
    }
  end
end
```

Having reindexed the Animal model you can search for it expecting to match against any available translations:

```
Animal.search("dog")
=> #<Searchkick::Relation [#<Animal id: 2, name: {"en"=>"dog", "fr"=>"chien"}, created_at: "2024-03-29 04:09:54.463595000 +0000", updated_at: "2024-03-29 04:43:27.339374000 +0000">]>

Animal.search("chien")
=> #<Searchkick::Relation [#<Animal id: 2, name: {"en"=>"dog", "fr"=>"chien"}, created_at: "2024-03-29 04:09:54.463595000 +0000", updated_at: "2024-03-29 04:43:27.339374000 +0000">]>

Animal.search("cane")
=> #<Searchkick::Relation []>
```